# range-based for on STL containers

Tags: stl, for-loop, c++11

I am using heavily `BOOST_FOREACH` for iteration over containers, and since I moved to c++0x recently, I thought I could replace `BOOST_FOREACH` with range-based `for` construct. The following piece of code

```
#include<vector>
#include<boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include<boost/range.hpp>
using std::vector; using boost::shared_ptr;
class Node;
int main(void){
   vector<shared_ptr<Node>> nodes;
   for(const shared_ptr<Node>& n: nodes);
}
```

does not compile with `gcc` 4.6, leading to

```
error: call of overloaded 'end(std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Node> >&)' is ambiguous
note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/range_access.h:78:5: note: decltype (__cont->end()) std::end(const _Container&) [with _Container = std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Node> >, decltype (__cont->end()) = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const boost::shared_ptr<Node>*, std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Node> > >]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/range_access.h:68:5: note: decltype (__cont->end()) std::end(_Container&) [with _Container = std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Node> >, decltype (__cont->end()) = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<boost::shared_ptr<Node>*, std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Node> > >]
/usr/include/boost/range/end.hpp:103:47: note: typename boost::range_iterator<const T>::type boost::end(const T&) [with T = std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Node> >, typename boost::range_iterator<const T>::type = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const boost::shared_ptr<Node>*, std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Node> > >]
/usr/include/boost/range/end.hpp:92:41: note: typename boost::range_iterator<C>::type boost::end(T&) [with T = std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Node> >, typename boost::range_iterator<C>::type = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<boost::shared_ptr<Node>*, std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Node> > >]
```

Is there a way to avoid such ambiguity, or is range-based for simply unusable in such situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tricky. You're pulling in `std::end` and `boost::end` because the associated namespaces of `std::vector<boost::shared_ptr>` are both `std` and `boost`. Both are templates that match.

However, a non-template `end()` would be an even better match. So, just provide your own:

```
inline std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Node> >::iterator
   end(std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Node> > vsn&)
{
  return std::end(vsn); 
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! I tried a minimal exmaple and it breaks only if I #include<boost/range.hpp>. I will edit the question to show it.

Comment: Hm... It would be better to have something more universal, as here for each containers type 4 iterators (begin, const begin, end, const end) have to be wrapped that way.Hopefully `boost::serialization` will support `std::shared_ptr` soon and I will be able to abandon `boost::shared_ptr` :-|

Comment: @eudoxos: This issue [will be fixed](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Range-begin-end-ADL-issues-in-C-0x-range-based-for-td3093206.html) in future Boost releases.

Comment: Was that original problem only because of the `using` directives, or would that always have been resolved wrongly no matter what?

Comment: Would have been wrong always; it's an ADL issue. It doesn't matter how you name the types, the associated namespaces are determined by the types themselves. Even a typedef wouldn't matter.

Comment: Additional information:  gcc 4.6 is in error.  The range-based for-loop was changed to avoid this problem just this past March (probably after gcc 4.6 was set in concrete).  The compiler should *first* check `vector` for member `begin` and `end` and use those if found (which it will in this example).  Only if the member `begin` and `end` are not found will it resort to ADL.

Comment: @Howard Hinnant This is corrected in the working version GCC 4.7.